# How to use Bootstrap datetime control

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I need to use datetime picker control in my MVC 4 application.
For that, I have installed `bootstrap 3-datetimepicker` nuget package and below related files are referred.

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<link href="Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--renamed - .less file to .css and referred here !>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>    
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Html code:

```
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <input type="text" id="dpicker" class="form-control" />
       </div>
     </div>
```

JS code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dpicker").datetimepicker({ format: 'mm-dd-yyyy' });
});
```

Though, on click of textbox no date picker is open.

What is the issue in above code to use bootstrap date time picker control ?

Thanks

Comment: the code should be executed after the html is loaded, just saying

Comment: provide your HTML code so that we can find the issue !

Comment: any error shown in browser console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `date` class to `input` first parent, i.e: `<div class='row date'>`.

Then it will work.

Here is working **snippet**

```js
$(function(){
$('#dpicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

 <div class="container">
      <div class="row date">
        <input type="text" id="dpicker" class="form-control" />
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: thanks. it works. I was using another package boostrap datetime picker but as seen your answer, using with `Bootstrap.Datepicker` nuget package and it fixes. also, added `date` class that sovles. thanks.